# Retain open tab after page refresh / bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code which shows two menus in two tabs, How do I stop the currently open tab from resetting after a page refresh?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
                                    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
                                });
                                var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
                                if(activeTab){
                                    $('#subtabs a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
                                }
                            });
                            </script>

                        <ul id="subtabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#artists" aria-controls="artists" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Artists</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#subjects" aria-controls="subjects" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Subjects</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="artists">
                                <ul> 
                                <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'artist', 'posts_per_page' => -1 )) ; while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="subjects">
                                <ul>
                                <?php $tax_terms = get_terms('subject');

                                    foreach($tax_terms as $term) {

                                        $term_link = get_term_link($term);

                                        if (is_wp_error($term_link)) {
                                            continue;
                                        } ?>

                                        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($term_link); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>   

                                <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be using localStorage. Every time you click on the tab list just add it to localstorage and on reload get the item and that specific class to that particular tab which would make it active.

Here is the link from tutorialrepublic: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=bootstrap-keep-last-selected-tab-active-on-page-refresh

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... maybe flesh out the answer with an example.. I would of suggested this too, or possibly the use of a cookie

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This looks like the solution, I have tried it and still no luck, I have updated my question with this solution in mind.

Comment: Hey @BradFletcher, I checked it and it works.

Comment: check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/reddysridhar53/orr9aoor/1/

Comment: I got it working, I had to move the jquery.js and bootstrap.js to the header from the footer.